# Get parameters out of callback function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a function that looks like this:

```
main.add = function(){
    var newTabId;
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"enter.html","active":true},
        function(tab) {
            newTabId = tab.id;
        }
    );
    console.log(newTabId);
}
```

But when `newTabId` is printed to console the chrome.tabs.create function hasn't run so the var is `undefined`.

Is there any way to ensure the code from the chrome namespace finishes before running anything below it?

Comment: Put your code directly in the callback function. `function(tab) {newTabId = tab.id; console.log(newTabId); ...}`

Answer (score 0):

First, do newTabId global, defining it outside the function.  Your two "newTabId" belong to different namespaces.

Secondo, the function inside chrome.tabs.create will start after your main code finish.  It's asynchronous programming.  chrome API is all asynchronous, so, get used to it, there's no workaround, sadly.

If you want to start thinking asynchronous, I recommend using [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) with jQuery's [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).